# Android 11 | give Python script access to Android directory

Tags: python-3.x, file, android-11

I'm trying to get permission to edit a file from an other app in the Android/obb directory on Android 11. It crashes on this line because of it:
`makedirs​(​"/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/com.ea.game.pvz2_row (1)"​, ​exist_ok​ ​=​ ​True​)`

- Can I get this permission with [Pydroid permissions plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroidpermissionsplugin&hl=en&gl=US)
- Can I use another app to run Python?
- Or do I have to build my Python script asking for permissions.
  I don't have an Android 11 device for testing.
  [image]

Comment: "Is it a problem with Android 11 maybe" -- yes, insofar as you do not have write access to that location, most likely.

Comment: I don't know I have no way to verify nor find a solution, do you have Android 11?

Comment: Yes. You do too, at least in the form of emulators.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't install them on my machine without admin. Could you be so nice to just run the command with Pydroid3 on Android 11 please.

Comment: I do not know Pydroid3 but it has noting to do with Pydroid3. That obb directory is not accessable. Not even when the app has 'all files access'. File.canRead() and File.canWrite() both return false. Always use these two functions together with File.exists() before you try an operation. You can then warn the user.

Comment: The obb dir is not accessable. But you can call Context.getObbDirs() and a package directory will be created to which your app has access. Looking at your code its unclear what directory you try to make.